# Using garchFit to fit an ARCH(1) process

Tags: r, time-series, garch

I tried using the garchFit function FinTs library. This is what I am trying to run:

```
garchFit(formula=~arma(0,1,2)+garch(0,1), data$`1 YR`)
```

However I get the following error:

---

Error in .garchInitParameters(formula.mean = formula.mean, formula.var = formula.var,  : 
  The order p must be > 0 in GARCH/APARCH(p,q)

---

But if I use the garch function from the ts library with the following code:

```
garch(data$`1 YR`,order=c(0,1),trace=F)
```

This runs but I don't know how to use this object to forecast. 
Please help me out with both. Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome. The error message says that the parameter `p` should be strictly greater than `0`. So, does the code run without errors when you use `garchFit(formula =~ arma(1,1,2) + garch(1,1), data$'1 YR')` instead?

Comment: Yes it does. Although I tried     arma(0,1,2). But I want to fit an Arch(1) process on the residual not a Garch process.

Comment: isn't arma only two parameter so 1,2,2 is invalid?